# Why can't I call the server method directly, but just add intermediate variables?

Tags: go, mqtt

I'm writing a client for mqtt.
I wrote a callback for mqtt.OnConnectHandler.
I want to write the connection address of the print server.

```golang
var connectHandler mqtt.OnConnectHandler = func(c mqtt.Client) {
    
        // this is ok 
    options := c.OptionsReader()
    s := options.Servers()
        fmt.Printf("conn: %s success\n", s)

        // --------------------------------------
        // But it won't work like this
        // here have error： On servers。
        // cannot call pointer method Servers on mqtt.ClientOptionsReadercompilerInvalidMethodExpr

    o := c.OptionsReader().Servers()    
    fmt.Printf("conn: %s success\n", o)


}
```

so ，I found that I couldn't use it directly. why？
Aren't they the same thing?
Why can I only use intermediate variables to receive it?

I tried two ways.
There is only one success.
I thought both would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `Servers` method is declared with a pointer receiver. That means in order to call `Servers`, the receiver must be addressable:

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators

A temporary variable is not addressable. Here:

```
c.OptionsReader().Servers()
```

`c.OptionsReader()` returns a value that is not addressable, so you cannot call `Servers` using that as the receiver. When you assign the return value of `c.OptionsReader` to a variable, then it becomes addressable, and you can call `Servers()` using that variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 'A temporary variable is not addressable.` made me understand my question.

If c.OptionsReader() returns a pointer, can I directly call it?

 ```go
 func (c *client) OptionsReader() ClientOptionsReader {
  r := ClientOptionsReader{options: &c.options}
  return r
 }
 
 // change to
 func (c *client) OptionsReader() *ClientOptionsReader {
  r := ClientOptionsReader{options: &c.options}
  return &r
 }
 
 ```